# What is the preferred way to schedule a Windows Server 2003 Job

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-task-scheduler

Having spent the last decade primarily on Linux systems, my Windows knowledge is a bit rusty, and I am out looking things up as well as asking here. Also, I am not looking for a discussion, but, instead, an answer indicating best practice.

Does scheduling a task in Windows infer the same kind of process as cron in Linux? That is, I am assuming a Windows scheduled tasks works without a user being logged in?

Is Windows 2003 Task Scheduler the preferred way to schedule a task?

If Task Scheduler is not the right thing, what is another preferred way?

The task I want to schedule is pscp.exe to grab a file on a SAMBA share and send it to a vendor on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Windows 2003 Task Scheduler the preferred way to schedule a task?

Task Scheduler is the de-facto Windows equivalent of `cron`. So, yes, use it to schedule a recurring task :)

> I am assuming a Windows scheduled tasks works without a user being logged in?

That depends on how you configure the task:

[image]

Besides the GUI available through the Control Panel, there are [additional CLI tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738335(v=ws.10).aspx) to add tasks. The [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx) tool should be of special interest here.